# Simulate a while loop in PHP

Tags: php, smarty, while-loop

I'm building something in a system that utilizes smarty version 2. The code I'm writing needs to utilize a `while` loop, however, the `while` loop was not introduced until version 3.

Can you simiulate a `while` loop using something like `for` or `foreach`? Maybe looping using two conditions or breaking out prematurely? What are my options?

PS: Installing the plugin to provide `while` loop functionality is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A for loop while loop is like so:

```
for(;(put your while condition here);){

}
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/KPBUk4ZN

[Read here for converting native PHP to smarty](http://www.nusphere.com/php/templates_smarty_functions1.htm)

Comment: So have the index be intialized to 0 outside the loop, increment inside the loop, have a bool be the condition within the `for` line, and change the bool based on another variable that keeps track of the current condition and whether it has been satisfied?

Comment: @Ryan, i mean whatever you want as your loop, i just did that, you can do what you want

Comment: @Ryan, try it out. Then you will know ^_^

Comment: Sorry, I deleted the comment since I just saw your second line. Thanks, I'll try it out.

Comment: The equivalent of `for` in PHP is `section` in smarty, but in `section` you have to indiciate the amount of loops, which is unknown, so I don't think this will work.

Comment: @Ryan, what do you need a while loop for? (if i may ask)

Comment: I need to display 5 things on the page, but only if they've never been displayed before. What has been displayed before is stored in a session. So I want to loop and get the data while I have not yet reached 5 to display.

Comment: The session data has already been displayed, so I only use that to check what not to display. The remaining data comes from the db, so I need to only display things on the site for as long as its not in the session.

Comment: @RyanS -- so use an array intersect and display the opposite information with a for loop...

Comment: Funny you mention that, I was just looking at the smarty doc to see if they have a function like that, but I didn't see one.

Comment: I was trying to stay true to the remaining document I'm working on, which doesn't use any PHP code directly, but I'm really running out of options here. Thanks for all your input!